# how to keep decimals in c

Tags: c, decimal

I am writing simple code for homework. 
I get one number from user, which is 3.4, when I define it with

```
scanf("%d",&a)
```

it takes only 3 and do it that way. I defined `a` as

```
int a;
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use float

```
float a;
scanf("%f", &a);
```

Comment: It should be noted that this will not result in 3.4 in `a`, just an approximation.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are very new to c programming. This is a very simple job. This can be done as:-

```
float a;
// to input a data in the variable a
scanf("%f",&a);
//to display the stored data
printf("%f\n",a);
//or 
printf("%.nf\n",a);//specify value of n
//maximum value of n is 6 also is its default value
//for e.g. printf("%.2f",a); will display decimal number upto two digits after the decimal place
//you can know more about displaying data as
%d: decimal value (int) 
%c: character (char) 
%s: string (const char *) 
%u: unsigned decimal value (unsigned int) 
%ld: long int (long) 
%f: float value (float or double) 
%x: decimal value in Hexadecimal format 
%o: decimal value in octal format
```

For avialabe list of formatting specifications go [here](http://icecube.wisc.edu/~dglo/c_class/printf.html)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. What will be the max `n` in `%.nlf` eg. `long float` or `double`?

Answer (score 1):

You should define `a` as

```
float a;
```

and replace `%d` with `%f` in `scanf`

```
scanf("%f", &a);
```

> What should I do?

Read [Basics of Formatted Input/Output in C](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/c_io.html).

Comment: and define a as a float, not an int

Answer (score 1):

%d is for int. 3.4 is not an int type, you can use float.

```
float x;
scanf("%f", &x);
```

For detailed information about data types, you can check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

And also here: http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/variables/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple for int variable we use %d format specifier and if we want float we use %f format specifier. Because according to IEEE int and float bit map format are different.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring int a which can take only integer value  so what  you have to do is make it float which is used for numbers having decimal point

float a;
scanf(%f,&a);