# decimal of numbers in c

Tags: c, decimal, printf, scanf

I just asked a question but couldn't get what I want, and couldn't edited and reply as it is too long. My question is the same and it is the link to that question.[how to keep decimals in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078805/how-to-keep-decimals-in-c)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float b,c,;
    int a,kk;
    printf("Welcome to the unit conversion program\n");
    printf("This program can convert the measurements of;\n");
    printf("1-Length\n");
    printf("2-Mass\n");
    printf("Please select the number that corresponds to the measurement you want to convert in:\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    if (a==1){
          printf("Your number will be converted from inches to centimeters.\n");
          printf("Please enter the length.\n");
          scanf("%f",&b);
          c=b*2.54;
          printf("%f inch is %f cm.",b,c);
          scanf("%d",kk); \. to avoid to shut the cmd windows .\
          }

      else if (a==2){
           printf("Your number will be converted from pounds (lbs) to kilograms");
           printf("Please enter the mass.\n");
           scanf("%d",&b);
           c=b*0.45359237;
           printf("%d lbs is %d kgs.",b,c);
       }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that `%d` in the format specifier of both `scanf` and `printf` represents **decimal**, so it expects an `int` (in the case of `scanf`, a pointer to `int`)

Since you are declaring `b` and `c` as `float`, `%d` in the lines

```
scanf("%d",&b);

printf("%d lbs is %d kgs.",b,c);
```

should be changed to `%f` respectively.

A little piece of advice: use `double` in stead of `float`. It provides more precision, its performance is better in many machines. The downside is that it occupies more space than `float`, but that's not a problem in most cases.

You should use `%f` in `printf` and `%lf` in `scanf` in case you are using `double`.

Comment: Why can't I explain my problem? Okay, but check if a=1, then code should work right? But it doesn't! Please do not consider the else if part when a=2, just check out the a=1.

Comment: @BerkDemir You need to be more specific about your problem, like your input, output and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
scanf("%d",&b);

printf("%d lbs is %d kgs.",b,c);
```

to:

```
scanf("%f",&b);

printf("%f lbs is %f kgs.",b,c);
```

You declared **b** as float and *taking input as a decimal & later printing both float b,c as decimal?* Please study a book `Deital & Deital for C/C++` is an *amazing book.*

Comment: Please do not consider else if part when a=2, just check the a=1

Comment: I don't see any error. Besides if you are consider `\. to avoid to shut the cmd windows .\` to be a comment. If so either remove it or change it to `/* to avoid to shut the cmd windows */`. Besides that I don't see any problem. **Define your problem**